# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python-3.7

I'm trying to make rock paper scissors game with python, but when I try to run it, I'll get this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'NoneType'

Here's the code:

```
import random
import time
import os
os.system("color 02")
Controls= ("Controls:\nR = Rock\nP = Papper\nS = Sicissors\n")
Moves = ['r','p','s']
Player_Wins = ['rs','sp','pr']
AI_Wins = ['sr','ps','rp']
P_Score = 0
AI_Score = 0
print("This is a game of rock paper scissors\n")
time.sleep(1)
print("To put it simply you will be facing against me\n\n(The computer!)\n")
print(Controls)
while True:
    P_Move = input("Your Move: ").lower
    AI_Move = print("AI Move:",random.choice(Moves))
    if P_Move + AI_Move in Player_Wins:
        print("\nYou Win!\n")
        P_Score = P_Score + 1
        print(P_Score)
    elif P_Move + AI_Move in AI_Wins:
        print("\nAI Win!\n")
        AI_Score = AI_Score + 1
        print(AI_Score)
    elif AI_Move == P_Move:
        print("Tie")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `P_Move` is a function, because `.lower` method is not called. Add `()` after that so it will be a string.

The `AI_Move` is not str too. It's `None`, because it's the result of print function which is nothing.

Correct code will be:

```
P_Move = input("Your Move: ").lower()
print("AI Move:")
AI_Move = random.choice(Moves)
```